# How to ensure matplotlib in a Python 3 virtualenv uses the TkAgg backend?

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, virtualenv, matplotlib

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3. Using APT to install `python3-matplotlib` and then printing the matplotlib backend gives `TKAgg`, which is expected because Ubuntu has 16.04 has `python3-tk` installed. This is done by running:

```
sudo apt install python3-matplotlib
python3 -c 'import matplotlib as mpl; print(mpl.get_backend())'
```

However, if I create a virtualenv for Python 3, activate the virtualenv, install `matplotlib` using `pip` and then print the matplotlib backend, I get `agg` instead. This is done by running:

```
virtualenv venv -p python3
source venv/bin/activate
pip install matplotlib
python -c 'import matplotlib as mpl; print(mpl.get_backend())'
```

It looks like matplotlib in the virtualenv is not aware of the presence of the `TkAgg` backend in the system, which is not surprising given the virtualenv does not see the system site packages when the `--system-site-packages` option is not used. Forcing matplotlib to use the `TkAgg` backend and then importing `matplotlib.pyplot` gives `ImportError: cannot import name '_tkagg'` as expected. This is done by running:

```
python -c "import matplotlib as mpl; mpl.use('TkAgg'); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"
```

Therefore, how do I ensure that matplotlib in a Python 3 virtualenv uses the `TkAgg` backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the `tk-dev` package by running:

```
sudo apt install tk-dev
```

Then, reinstall matplotlib in the virtualenv by running:

```
pip --no-cache-dir install -U --force-reinstall matplotlib
```

Verify the TkAgg backend is used by checking if the following code returns `TkAgg`:

```
python -c 'import matplotlib as mpl; print(mpl.get_backend())'
```